# Python returns an empty list during web scraping using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get(url="https://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/best-movies-2/")

webpage_text = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage_text, "html.parser")

title_list = soup.find_all(name="h3", class_="jsx-4245974604")

print(title_list)
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLuxV.png , Here is the link to the img which show the name and class of the element

Comment: As we see so often here, you have not actually looked at the HTML for this page.  Go bring this up on your browser and do "View Source".  There are no `<h3>` tags anywhere on that page.  The DOM is all built up by Javascript.  You will need to use a browser, like Selenium, to get the dynamic info.

Comment: You seems to have made a screenshot of the DOM, but beautifulsoup does not operate on the DOM, it operates on the HTML source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find data in `img` tag using specific class and it will return the lists and use `alt` attribute get data

```
data=soup.find_all("img",class_="jsx-952983560 loading")[1:]
for d in data:
    print(d['alt'])
```

Output:

```
Reservoir Dogs
Groundhog Day
Paddington 2
Amelie
....
```

Comment: May i know where can i find the documention of it?

Comment: Search for attributes in [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc.zh/)